# Cassandra cluster throughput throttled

Tags: performance, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra, and hope to get some help from people who ever met this before.

Currently, I have application severs and Cassandra clusters reside in both east and west Amazon ec2 regions.  And I got such a weird performance test result below, which means when application sever and C* cluster are in same region(I believe they use internal IP), throughput is throttled; while when application sever and C* cluster are across region, throughput is scalable.

West C* and East C* have exactly the same hardware and schema. 2 application servers are identical too.

```
west app sever -> west C* cluster      throttled
west app sever -> east C* cluster      scalable
east app sever -> east C* cluster      throttled
east app sever -> west C* cluster      scalable
```

cassandra.yaml.

```
cluster_name: 'STEAST'
initial_token: -9223372036854775808
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /raid0/cassandra/data

commitlog_directory: /raid0/cassandra/commitlog
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
saved_caches_directory: /raid0/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32

seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.239.xxx.xxx"

concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
memtable_flush_queue_size: 4
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 10.239.xxx.xxx
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64
multithreaded_compaction: false
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
compaction_preheat_key_cache: true
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
phi_convict_threshold: 12
endpoint_snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: resources/dse/conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra

client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
internode_compression: all
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
preheat_kernel_page_cache: false
auto_bootstrap: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find there's a lock when compiling prepared statements. I was compiling a new prepared statement whenever a new request come in, after I changed to reuse it I got my app server scale. However, I still don't know why cross-region case can scale.